# Sorting problem by position

Tags: magento-1.7, sorting, position

I use Magento 1.7. The sorting by position dont work in both directions. The url-parameter switch from asc to desc but nothing change in the sorting.

Where could be the problem an in which are the files where Magento sort by position?

Thanks

Comment: but you set positions for products in the current category ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by roman204 you would need to make sure that the position has been assigned for the product in this category. You can do this via Catalog > Categories:

[image: Magento sort by position]

Comment: Doesn't sound like this is his problem if switching from asc to desc does nothing....

Comment: I tried with no positions and without them changing the sort order does nothing like the OP mentioned.

Comment: Wow, strange. Seems like there's be at least some sorting at play regardless. I'll vote this answer up.